# Why does apt report different sizes for install and autoremove e.g. icedtea-plugin?

Tags: apt

This I have on install

```
$ sudo apt install icedtea-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following additional packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java icedtea-8-plugin icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
Suggested packages:
  openjdk-8-jre-jamvm fonts-ipafont-gothic fonts-ipafont-mincho fonts-indic
The following NEW packages will be installed:
  ca-certificates-java icedtea-8-plugin icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common icedtea-plugin openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
0 upgraded, 7 newly installed, 0 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
Need to get 28,6 MB of archives.
After this operation, 102 MB of additional disk space will be used.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
Get:1 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/main amd64 ca-certificates-java all 20160321 [12,9 kB]
Get:2 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre-headless amd64 8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 [27,0 MB]
Get:3 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial-updates/main amd64 openjdk-8-jre amd64 8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2 [69,3 kB]
Get:4 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 icedtea-netx-common all 1.6.2-3ubuntu1 [1 373 kB]
Get:5 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 icedtea-netx amd64 1.6.2-3ubuntu1 [26,9 kB]  
Get:6 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 icedtea-8-plugin amd64 1.6.2-3ubuntu1 [195 kB]
Get:7 http://ru.archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu xenial/universe amd64 icedtea-plugin all 1.6.2-3ubuntu1 [3 690 B]  
Fetched 28,6 MB in 32s (883 kB/s)                                                                            
Selecting previously unselected package ca-certificates-java.
(Reading database ... 523963 files and directories currently installed.)
Preparing to unpack .../ca-certificates-java_20160321_all.deb ...
Unpacking ca-certificates-java (20160321) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jre-headless_8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package openjdk-8-jre:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../openjdk-8-jre_8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-netx-common.
Preparing to unpack .../icedtea-netx-common_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking icedtea-netx-common (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-netx:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../icedtea-netx_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icedtea-netx:amd64 (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-8-plugin:amd64.
Preparing to unpack .../icedtea-8-plugin_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_amd64.deb ...
Unpacking icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Selecting previously unselected package icedtea-plugin.
Preparing to unpack .../icedtea-plugin_1.6.2-3ubuntu1_all.deb ...
Unpacking icedtea-plugin (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.2.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 174, your new list has 174
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
Processing triggers for desktop-file-utils (0.22-1ubuntu5.1) ...
Processing triggers for mime-support (3.59ubuntu1) ...
Warning: mailcap line not starting with a media type in emerald
Problematic line:  application/x-emerald-theme; nametemplate=%s.emerald
Processing triggers for gnome-menus (3.13.3-6ubuntu3.1) ...
Processing triggers for bamfdaemon (0.5.3~bzr0+16.04.20160824-0ubuntu1) ...
Rebuilding /usr/share/applications/bamf-2.index...
Processing triggers for hicolor-icon-theme (0.15-0ubuntu1) ...
Setting up ca-certificates-java (20160321) ...
Setting up icedtea-netx-common (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for ca-certificates (20160104ubuntu1) ...
Updating certificates in /etc/ssl/certs...
0 added, 0 removed; done.
Running hooks in /etc/ca-certificates/update.d...

done.
Updating Mono key store
Linux Cert Store Sync - version 4.2.1.0
Synchronize local certs with certs from local Linux trust store.
Copyright 2002, 2003 Motus Technologies. Copyright 2004-2008 Novell. BSD licensed.

I already trust 174, your new list has 174
Import process completed.
Done
done.
Setting up openjdk-8-jre-headless:amd64 (8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/jjs to provide /usr/bin/jjs (jjs) in auto mode
Setting up openjdk-8-jre:amd64 (8u131-b11-0ubuntu1.16.04.2) ...
Setting up icedtea-netx:amd64 (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/javaws to provide /usr/bin/javaws (javaws) in manual mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/itweb-settings to provide /usr/bin/itweb-settings (itweb-settings) in auto mode
update-alternatives: using /usr/lib/jvm/java-8-openjdk-amd64/jre/bin/policyeditor to provide /usr/bin/policyeditor (policyeditor) in auto mode
Setting up icedtea-8-plugin:amd64 (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Setting up icedtea-plugin (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
Processing triggers for libc-bin (2.23-0ubuntu9) ...
```

This when I tried autoremove

```
$ sudo apt autoremove icedtea-plugin
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
The following packages will be REMOVED:
  icedtea-plugin
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 1 to remove and 0 not upgraded.
After this operation, 19,5 kB disk space will be freed.
Do you want to continue? [Y/n] 
(Reading database ... 524256 files and directories currently installed.)
Removing icedtea-plugin (1.6.2-3ubuntu1) ...
```

Father invocations of remove/autoremove and purge do nothing.

It looks like as if dependencies of the icedtea-plugin would used by something after install and can't be anymore deleted. Nothing else was installed between install and remove the icedtea-plugin.

Ideas? Is it possible to make apt (or something else) completely delete all the installed software? I suppose I can use `dpkg` to remove them manually, but it's not the case.

**--UPDATE--**

```
$ apt-cache rdepends --installed ca-certificates-java icedtea-8-plugin icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common openjdk-8-jre openjdk-8-jre-headless
ca-certificates-java
Reverse Depends:
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
  ca-certificates
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
  openjdk-8-jre-headless
icedtea-8-plugin
Reverse Depends:
  openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre
icedtea-netx
Reverse Depends:
  icedtea-8-plugin
  icedtea-netx-common
icedtea-netx-common
Reverse Depends:
  icedtea-netx
openjdk-8-jre
Reverse Depends:
  icedtea-netx
  icedtea-8-plugin
openjdk-8-jre-headless
Reverse Depends:
  openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre
  openjdk-8-jre
```

Comment: Add the output of `apt-cache rdepends --installed ca-certificates-java icedtea-8-plugin icedtea-netx icedtea-netx-common openjdk-8-jre  openjdk-8-jre-headless`, please

Comment: Try `sudo apt-get purge ...` it should delete the package itself and all affiliated files.

Comment: It doesn't. From man apt-get `purge is identical to remove except that packages are removed and purged (any configuration files are deleted too).`